# Removing lines and bullet points - WP

Tags: css, wordpress

[Here's my blog (its not finished yet).](http://Www.louismoore.net/wordpress/)

In the side bar as you can see the 'recent posts' and many parts of the twitter feed are seperated by lines and have bullet points next to them.

I would like to remove these however I'm not sure how. Looking at the source code for the page I think that the line and bullet points are on 'a href' class.

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Grey.css line 95. There is a definition there for background-image grey/bullet.png and a border-bottom #b0b0b0.
If you want to remove both you can override this by adding the following to your embedded style:

```
.widget ul li a:link, .widget ul li a:visited {
    background-image: none; /* this can be your own custom background image if desired */
    border-bottom: none;    /* this can be your own desired color/thickness if desired */
}
```

Comment: make sure to also remove the background image for the hover effect

Comment: @Snowinferno I did what you said but it looks like this now... Louismoore.net/wordpress/

Comment: The embedded style sheet is the <style> tag, usually in the <head> element. I just took another look and realize it is wordpress. I don't have much experience building/modifying wordpress templates so I don't know exactly where you would add the <style> tag to the template to get it to show up, but you can just edit the grey.css file and change the indicated line to the suggested code I provided. As always, it is a good idea to make a backup of the file before changing it.